# A polynomial $p \in \Bbb C[z]$ has the property that $p(x)$ is real for all $x$ real. Then prove that $p$ has real coefficients.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was thinking that since $p(x)$ is real if and only if $x$ is real, then $p$ is linear. And since real polynomials are equal to the products of real linear and quadratic polynomials, $p$ must be real.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question: $p(z)\in\Bbb R$ for all $z\in\mathbb R$ is not the same as $p(z)\in\mathbb R$ if and only if $z\in\mathbb R$. Just consider $p(z)=z^2$; this is real on the real line but it is also real on the imaginary axis.

Comment: I edited your title to properly $\LaTeX$ify it; but I had to delete the phrase "with complex coefficients" to do so.  Hope this is OK.  Cheers!

Comment: To answer the question in the title, do the words Lagrange interpolation ring any bell ? (they also show how to generalize the question to arbitrary fields, and why it doesn't generalize to, say, integral domains)

Comment: Since p(x) is a real function of a real variable, the same is true of all its derivatives.  In particular $p^{(n)}(0) =n! a_n$ must be real, where $n$ is the order and $a_n$ is the leading coefficient.  Now iterate for each coefficient, you're done.

Comment: Thank you for making the changes and adding Latex! This question is for my Complex Analysis course and no we have not used Lagrange Interpolation. How exactly do I iterate for each coefficient?

Comment: The actual questions assumes that $p$ has complex coefficients.